# How often should Navigation software be updated?

Tags: navigation

I have a 2005 Lexus rx 330 with navigation system. How often should it be updated and how much does it cost approximately?

Answer (score 1):

Your system arrives with a pretty comprehensive map set when you first get it. The satnav companies will always advise regular updates and you pay for them. Most of the updates are of petty adjustments to the road system and are generally not worth paying for as the systems will re-calculate if you go off route anyway. To me it is simple up-selling when it comes to these updates.